# Marshalling Dynamo Data in Step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

I would like to write a data structure like this to DynamoDB via a step function:

```json
{
  "data": { "foo": "bar" },
  "id": "TEST-0123",
  "rev": "1.0.0",
  "source": "test",
  "streamId": "test-stream-1",
  "timestamp": 9999,
  "type": "TestExecuted",
  "version": 1
}
```

Data can be a deeply nested object.

I would prefer to not use lambda, if possible. So my question is: Is it possible to marshall this data into a form that can be inserted into a dynamodb table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input format has a fixed shape, you can marshal it into DynamoDB JSON in the DynamoDB integration's [task parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ddb.html) with JSON Path references.

If your input has an arbitrary shape, you'll need a Lambda Task (in which case you're probably better off using an SDK to marshal and perform the DynamoDB operation in one go).

Comment: Thank you. I had hoped there is a way to marshal arbitrary shaped data, but apparently this is not possible atm